# SQL - Transform Symbol's Column Values Into Columns with Symbols as Names and Type of Boolean

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, transpose

I have this table with the Symbol column:

[image]

I need to transform it into a table which has the Symbol's column values (distinct) as new Column Name. These columns should be of Type bool or INT (0/1). Resulting table should look like this below:

[image]

**P.S. What if the set of columns was dynamically generated by another query?**

Comment: SQL Server supports the [bit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603) data type. (Valid values are 0, 1, 'TRUE' and 'FALSE'.) There is a [boolean](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188074.aspx#Anchor_0) data type (with values TRUE, FALSE and UNKNOWN), but you cannot get a firm grip on one: "Unlike other SQL Server data types, a Boolean data type cannot be specified as the data type of a table column or variable, and cannot be returned in a result set."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need dynamic Columns, you would need Dynamic SQL

**Example**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = Stuff((Select Distinct ',' + QuoteName(Symbol)+'=case when symbol='''+Symbol+''' then 1 else 0 end ' From Yourtable  Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'') 

Select @SQL = '
Select '+@SQL+'
      ,PartOfDay
      ,isProfitable
 From  YourTable
'
Exec(@SQL)
```

**Returns**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just use `case`:

```
select (case when symbol = 'ACRX' then 1 else 0 end) as acrx,
       (case when symbol = 'ANF' then 1 else 0 end) as anf,
       (case when symbol = 'NVDA' then 1 else 0 end) as nvda,
       (case when symbol = 'rsx' then 1 else 0 end) as rsx,
       partofday, isprofitable
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```
select 
  IIF('ACRX', 1, 0) as acrx,
  IIF('ANF', 1, 0) as anf,
  IIF('NVDA', 1, 0) as nvda,
  IIF('RXS', 1, 0) as rsx,
  partofday, 
  isprofitable
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also apply pivot operator to the dynamic SQL.

For example:

```
create table test03
(
Symbol varchar(30),
PartOfDay int,
isProfitable int
)

insert into test03 values
('ACRX',3,0),
('ACRX',3,0),
('ANF',2,1),
('ANF',2,1),
('ANF',2,1),
('NVDA',3,1),
('RSX',3,0),
('RSX',3,0)

--Query

DECLARE @V_COLUMNS VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @V_SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @V_COLUMNS=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ','+QUOTENAME(Symbol) FROM test03 FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
--print @V_COLUMNS

SET @V_SQL='
;WITH CTE AS
(
select 
ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Symbol) as RN,
Symbol,
1 AS V_VALUE,
PartOfDay,
isProfitable
from test03
)
SELECT '+@V_COLUMNS+',PartOfDay,isProfitable
FROM CTE 
PIVOT 
(
COUNT(V_VALUE) FOR Symbol IN ('+@V_COLUMNS+')
) PVT'

--PRINT @V_SQL
EXEC(@V_SQL)

--Output
/*
ACRX        ANF         NVDA        RSX         PartOfDay   isProfitable
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ------------
1           0           0           0           3           0
1           0           0           0           3           0
0           1           0           0           2           1
0           1           0           0           2           1
0           1           0           0           2           1
0           0           1           0           3           1
0           0           0           1           3           0
0           0           0           1           3           0
*/
```